# Get the loop index of SKAction.repeat in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, sprite-kit

I am looking for a way to get the loop index of a SKAction.repeat loop.

In the following code I would like to replace 'LOOP_INDEX' with the index of the repeat.

Is this even possible?

```
node.run(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.run { node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false },
// HERE
    SKAction.repeat(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: jumpHeight / CGFloat(sequences), duration: sequenceTimes[LOOP_INDEX]), count: sequences - 1),
    SKAction.run { node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true },
    SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: jumpHeight / CGFloat(sequences), duration: sequenceTimes[2]),
]), withKey: "jump")
```

Thanks for your answers ;)

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way.  SKAction.moveby is going to return an instance which gets passed in as a parameter to your repeat count.  Repeat is literally going to call the same instance over and over. What is the point of your code?  Sounds to me like all you want to do is change the timingMode of your action